# Cognito authentication keeps retrying forever, without throwing exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-cognito

I have a simple test code for Cognito authentication code in Java with Spring Boot. It works fine on my local, but when I on my remote server (CentOS) it acts very weirdly. If a user does not exist in the pool. keeps creating and recreating new threads and sending the request.

The code:

```
protected boolean isValidCognito(String username, String password) {

        // Retrieving the AWS credentials from the default instance profile credentials instead of ".withCredentials()".
        // More info on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html
        AWSCognitoIdentityProvider awsCognitoIDPClient = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard().build();

        Map<String,String> authParams =new HashMap<>();
        authParams.put("USERNAME", username);
        authParams.put("PASSWORD", password);

        AdminInitiateAuthRequest initialRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
                .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH)
                .withAuthParameters(authParams)
                .withClientId(COGNITO_CLIENT_ID)
                .withUserPoolId(COGNITO_POOL_ID);

        try {
            // NOTE: I know the request is being sent for sure, so we probably get at least this far
            AdminInitiateAuthResult initialResponse = awsCognitoIDPClient.adminInitiateAuth(initialRequest);
            Map<String, String> challengeParams = initialResponse.getChallengeParameters();
            String cognitoUserIdForSrp = challengeParams.get("USER_ID_FOR_SRP");
            String cognitoUserAttributes = challengeParams.get("userAttributes");
            logger.debug("Cognito authenticated user ID: " + cognitoUserIdForSrp
                    + " with user attributes: " + cognitoUserAttributes);
            return true;
        } catch (NotAuthorizedException nae) {
            logger.error("Invalid Cognito username/password provided for " + authParams.get("USERNAME"));
            return false;
        } catch (AWSCognitoIdentityProviderException acipe) {
            logger.error("Amazon Cognito Identity Provider Error!");
            logger.debug("Make sure the user exists in the pool, and ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH is enabled.");
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unexpected Error: ", e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Logs if it helps:

```
2020-02-25 17:14:54.919 TRACE 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-98] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [METHOD_NAME]
2020-02-25 17:14:54.926 TRACE 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-98] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [METHOD_NAME]
2020-02-25 17:14:54.935 TRACE 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-98] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [METHOD_NAME]
2020-02-25 17:14:54.942 TRACE 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-98] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [METHOD_NAME]
2020-02-25 17:14:54.950 DEBUG 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-98] c.c.c.r.persistence.CognDaoImpl  : There is a user migrated to Cognito with user_id: SOME_UUID
2020-02-25 17:14:54.950  INFO 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-98] c.c.c.r.c.AuthenticationController       : my_email@mailinator.com has been migrated. Using Cognito for authentication.


2020-02-25 17:14:56.655 TRACE 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-160] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [METHOD_NAME]
2020-02-25 17:14:56.673 TRACE 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-160] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [METHOD_NAME]
2020-02-25 17:14:56.683 TRACE 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-160] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [METHOD_NAME]
2020-02-25 17:14:56.692 TRACE 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-160] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [METHOD_NAME]
2020-02-25 17:14:56.705 DEBUG 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-160] c.c.c.r.persistence.CogDaoImpl  : There is a user migrated to Cognito with user_id: SOME_UUID
2020-02-25 17:14:56.705  INFO 25144 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-160] c.c.c.r.c.AuthenticationController       : my_email@mailinator.com has been migrated. Using Cognito for authentication.

...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently wrong with "creating and recreating threads". If you have too many threads, your jvm will run out of memory or your process will die because you have hit some system limits. If you think your code is going into a loop, you need to find out who is calling your code and analyze that part of your code. Perhaps a thread-dump may help.